# Query multiple videos on youtube api

Tags: javascript, api, youtube

I am using an api to find videos on youtube. However, I would like to insert multiple queries into the same query, aiming to get results from two or more querys on the same return.

Example:

```
import * as YoubuteApi from "simple-youtube-api";

// multiple code here


// query: intitle: chess OR intitle: kasparov
youtube.instance().query('intitle: chess OR intitle: kasparov');
```

The expected result was to return videos for both queries. However, there is no return or no new videos.

Comment: can you provide the full code in your question? - I'm not sure which API you're using. Also you said: `I would like to insert multiple queries into the same query` - why not make multiple quesries instead?

Comment: I solved the problem very simply: just sending one keyword per query. This api is a Node API that mediates the youtube api. However, as I said above, by using the youtube API, only one query with intitle is allowed. Note that the OR operator does not work as in a google search.

Comment: Paulo, I'm glad you solved your problem and I encourage you to post your answer ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)) - and [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and so, you'll help other people in this community. Thank you.

Comment: This was very simple to fix: the OR operator cannot be used to concatenate queries. So I had no alternative but to do one query at a time (unfortunately)

Comment: Paulo, interesting. I encourage you to post your answer ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)) - and [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and so, you'll help other people in this community - also, comments are temporarely and might be deleted, so your contribution in the comments section will be lost. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My only solution was to make separate queries for each search because the OR operator doesn't work.

```
import * as YoubuteApi from "simple-youtube-api";

// multiple code here


// query: intitle: chess OR intitle: kasparov
youtube.instance().query('intitle: kasparov');
youtube.instance().query('intitle: chess');
```